# Как перезапустить скрипт Python внутри try except?

Tags: python, python-3.x, исключения, try

Есть скрипт Sarm.py:

```
try:
    #Какой-то код
except Exception:
    #Если исключение, перезапускаем Sarm.py
```

Пробовал так:

```
import os, sys
try:
    #Какой-то код
except Exception:
    os.execv(sys.executable, [sys.executable] + sys.argv)
```

Но почему-то скрипт просто висит.

Comment: Вы можете свой скрипт в функцию сделать, а потом при ошибке например вызывать функцию все будет циклично)

Comment: Вот данная [Статья](https://techarks.ru/qa/python/kak-perezapustit-python-scr-L3/) поможет вам.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Оно «зависает», потому что выполняется синхронно / зацикливается.

Попытка: Запускать через N секунд. Чтобы при этом контролировать процесс, если вдруг что-то пойдет не так (зациклятся ошибки):

```
import os, sys

def main():
    # Ваш «Какой-то код...»
    raise Exception


try:
    main()
except Exception:
    print("Moo...")

    from threading import Timer
    Timer(2.0, lambda: os.execv(sys.executable, [sys.executable] + sys.argv)).start()
```

Проблема: Вызовы «Накапливаются», после около сотни вызовов, такой код выдает `OSError: [Errno 12] Not enough space`.

---

Если оно должно вызываться бесконечно, пока не завершится без ошибки, можно сделать цикл вложенных вызовов с помощью функции:

```
from threading import Timer

def loop():
    loop.call_count += 1

    if loop.call_count > 10:
        print("Nope...")
        return # Ограничение попыток: Выход из функции на 11-м вызове.

    try:
        # Весь ваш код (синхронный)
        raise Exception

        # Может быть неудобно писать код прямо тут.
        # Вместо этого, можно сделать другой файл с кодом, а здесь выполнять
        # import file

    except Exception:
        print("Err...")
        Timer(0.5, loop).start() # раз в полсекунды.

loop.call_count = 0

loop()
```

Comment: А вы не знаете как остановить таймер? Например после 10-ой неудачной попытки? Глянул, написано с помощью cancel(). Но как его прописать если таймер каждый раз новый?

Comment: @Denzel Завести переменную-счетчик, считающую кол-во вызовов. Дойдет до 10 - не запускать таймер. Добавлено в ответ.